# YARN resource manager message losgstash

Tags: logstash, hadoop-yarn, logstash-grok, resourcemanager

I am trying to generate pie chart based on the final status of the job from RM logs. Since "**RESULT=**" string is in the "**message**" of the log, we are not able to extract it.

After doing some research we came to know that we need to write a grok pattern to break this string and extract "**RESULT=**".

Here is the string that I want to break, I want to extract user and result from this.

```
message:2017-02-28 21:24:44,223 INFO resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger (RMAuditLogger.java:logSuccess(191)) - USER=test1    OPERATION=Application Finished - Succeeded    TARGET=RMAppManager    RESULT=SUCCESS    APPID=application_1486072728057_33195
```

Comment: Will the above log line be in the same format always, despite the values?

Comment: You need only the value of `RESULT` or `RESULT=SUCCESS` itself ?

Comment: @Darth_vader Yes, it will be same all the time. I am looking for RESULT, since might have RESULT=SUCCESS or RESULT=FAILURE or RESULT=KILLED